# ValueError: Value of 'dimensions_0' is not the name of a column in 'data_frame'. after displaying scatterplot

Tags: python

I'm trying to visualize my data so I tried the following code and I get an error.

```
  dataset = pd.read_csv(r'/Users/Downloads/dataset/datasets/mydatasets/out_4.csv')
  df = dataset[["diffTime","diffP","diffS","diffH","diffE","diffA"]].to_numpy()
  out=dataset["labels"]
  import plotly.express as px

  df = df.reshape(-1)
  features = ["diffTime","diffP","diffS","diffH","diffE","diffA"]
    
  fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    df,
    dimensions=features,
    color="out"
  )
  fig.update_traces(diagonal_visible=False)
  fig.show()
```

Here is what I get as error:

> ValueError: Value of 'dimensions_0' is not the name of a column in
> 'data_frame'. Expected one of [0] but received: diffTime

I appreciate if anyone helps me to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the same column names in your `df`. When you convert it to numpy, the structure changes.
Or, after the reshape, change it to pandas and add the columns.

```
df = dataset[["diffTime","diffP","diffS","diffH","diffE","diffA"]]
dim = df.columns

fig = px.scatter_matrix(
    df,
    dimensions=dim ,
    color="out"
)
```

It should work.